# Best practice to read data from EMR to physical server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

I am using pyspark to read data from EMR. But if the EMR cluster is fully occupied, I can see on the cluster manager that all the memories are occupied by some ETL job, still can I run this script on my physical server that bring data from the EMR cluster to my physical server ?
what is the best practice suggest ?

Will it take the same amount of time to read the data from EMR to physical server? how does it handle the request if it is requested to read the data when it is fully occupied on EMR?

What kind of processes are executed on EMR (s3 bucket) while accessing/reading data from physical server through s3 utility?

Can I pull data to physical server when EMR cluster is fully occupied? If no, why ?

Thanks and Regards

Comment: What do you mean by "the s3 cluster"?

Comment: What do you mean by "s3 cluster is fully occupied"? Is this something inside Pyspark? Also, what is an "IDC server"?

Comment: I mean Amazon EMR, I reframe the question.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to *expand* your cluster and do things consistently.  I strongly suggest that you do not develop out-of-band/one-off processes that move things outside of the normal flow of work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply...already know but need some supportive best practices that can support, why pulling the data from occupied S3 cluster to physical server is not a good idea.....

Comment: We both need to understand why it's a Best Practice to create multiple ETL tooling (cluster/server) to do the same job/work.  If you can give me a reason this is a best practice I'll help you find a way to do it.  I maintain this will only add complexity, and make data lineage more difficult and I don't feel you have sufficiently described the payoff for doing this.

Comment: Can I pull data to physical server when S3 cluster is fully occupied? If no, why ?